# Xamarin.Forms Google Maps Api's direction library using

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, xamarin.forms

[image]

I would like to use the directions on "travel time" library in Xamarin.Forms in GoogleApi's application.

I found this source.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#traffic-model

The calculations I want to do have already been made and have been developed online using GoogleApi again. Very successful results are turning.

`enter code here`https://codepen.io/youfoundron/pen/GIlvp

I have little knowledge of the use of Api. That is why I could not understand the steps I needed to follow when I applied my Xamarin.Forms. It may be a simple and simple question, but I have had to ask because I have not been able to start for hours, thank you.

Comment: You can probably start by downloading this sample code on Xamarin.Forms working with maps - [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/xamarin-forms/WorkingWithMaps/) and the documentation here [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/).

Comment: @ADimaano I've already added the Xamarin.Forms.Maps plugin. But there is not much here except for a few simple features. I specifically want to use traveltime Json in GoogleApi.

Comment: [TKCustomMap](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap) might help you. Codes are available in github. So you can study them as well. I think this plugin has most of the stuff that you want.